# Algorithm to find equivalent classes of homotopic pathes on a grid with obstacles

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path, square-grid, path

Given a $n \times n$ grid with some walls and two cells $a$ and $b$, I want to compute the non-homotopics paths from $a$ to $b$ on this grid. A path is a sequence of adjacent cells (diagonal does not count) such that from one cell to another, we never go through a wall. We also ask our path to be non-looping, that is that they do not cross a given cell twice. Two paths are homotopic if we can deform one into another while still having valid paths through the deformation.  A wall is a boundary between two adjacent cells.

More formally, two paths $p$ and $q$ are homotopic if there exists a sequence of paths $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_n$ such that $p_0 = p$, $p_n =q$ and for all pair of paths $p_i$ and $p_{i+1}$, every cell of one of those paths is adjacent to a cell in the other path. Equivalently (I believe) it means that the loop formed by following $p$ from $a$ to $b$ and then $q$ from $b$ to $a$ does not contain walls.  This forms an equivalence relation on non-looping paths.  I would like an algorithm that outputs one path from each equivalence class.

Here is an example of some non-homotopic pathes with three walls. The setting *is* discrete but this was easier to draw like this. Taking any two path on this image, we see that there is always a wall inside the shape they create.

[image: A grid with some non-homotopic pathes between two poins]

From there, what I am looking for is an algorithm such that, given $n$ and a list with the positions of the walls computes a list containing a path (ideally the smallest) in each class of homotopic paths.

Comment: Idea: In your image, every wall can either be passed on the left or the right. So for any ordering of walls, different strings like LLR or RLR should result in different paths. Some care must be taken for paths that are equivalent across different wall-orderings. Having the start/end at the bottom/top doesn't lose generality because you can just rotate the coordinates without changing the problem.

Comment: @D.W. Homotopic is defined here as a property between two paths (think "isomorphic"). He is asking to compute a maximal set of pairwise-non-homotopic paths _(from all non-looping paths)_, ie. compute one path from each of the homotopic equivalence classes.

Comment: What cells count as adjacent - do diagonal cells count as adjacent?

Comment: By adjacent cells I mean cells with Manhattan distance equal to $1$, so the diagonal cells do not count.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft This is an interesting idea but it gets complicated when there is a wall "behind" the starting point as there are three paths that deals with it : one that ignores it, one that goes around by the left and one that goes around by the right.

Comment: There can be exponential number of equivalence classes here. So, we can not expect a polynomial running algorithm.

Comment: Right, exponential in the number of walls. But the number of walls shouldn't go to high in my setting.